# Adding a Value to Format(Range("a1"), "MMMM yyyy")

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to make a BACK-UP of current report to a separate folder and I'm wondering if there is a way to add a Value within the Format function.

Example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
   "\\<IP ADDRESS>\" & Format(Range("a1") + 32, "MMMM yyyy") & "\<file name>" & Format(Range("a1"), "mm dd yy")&".xlsx"

In my Workbook, Cell A1 is 09/01/2014
```

When I run the macro, I get an error. Can someone please point me in the right direction on this one? I have 15-20 files I have to BACK-UP this way.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?  Without your exact data we can't replicate it.

Comment: "I get an error" is not a problem description unless you tell us what that error is, including *the exact error message you're seeing*. You have that information available; there's no reason not to provide it to us as well if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula looks fine, provided that the file name doesn't contain any illegal characters, and the folder exists.  Make sure that the active sheet is the one with the date on it.  If it will not be, save the date to a variable before changing sheets, or build the date you want programatically.

Like:

```
theDate = Range("a1")

<sheet change>

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "\\<IP ADDRESS>\" & Format(theDate + 32, "MMMM yyyy") _
    & "\<file name>" & Format(theDate, "mm dd yy")&".xlsx"
```

If the folder **Format(theDate + 32, "MMMM yyyy")** doesn't exist you have to create it first:

```
MkDir \\<IP ADDRESS>\" & Format(theDate + 32, "MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: I just discovered the DateAdd function. DateAdd("m", 1, Range("a1")) will give me what I am looking. I thank you for your assistance as well.